# How to transfer files from another server, using FTP, in PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to find a way to transfer files from server-to-server. The source server can be any platform, and we may not even really know anything about it except that it supports FTP.

A number of posts I have found on SO recommend using scp, sftp, rsync, or wget for this purpose. Given that this PHP script needs to work every time, and the only thing we know for sure is that the source server supports FTP, how can this be achieved?

I found a couple FTP examples on SO, but they weren't explained very well.

We need to be able to download all files and folders, keeping the same directory structure as well.

Comment: If you want to use the old `FTP` protocol, then you have to use a php client, easiest is to use the ftp extension php provides. sftp and rsync are out in this case, since you need another server on the remote side for those. I suggest you simply take a look at the documentation, it is well written and comes with good explanations: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php With that knowledge, make a few test scripts. If you then run into issues you caanot resolve, then is the time to ask here posting your existing code.

Comment: To clarify, can rsync work without any configuration on the source server? Also, SFTP requires an SSL certificate to be installed on the Source, doesn't it?

Comment: rsync can use different protocols, but it has to be installed itself on the remote system. Also you need an rsync client on the local system. There is a PECL extension, but that has to be installed on the local system. So there is no direct answer to this. sftp does not require a certificate, no. It is based on ssh (typically openssh) is used these days, so you make want to use keys instead of passwords, maybe you even have to.

Comment: Neither of those options will work, since we cannot access the Source other than by FTP. I'll keep looking for a solution.

Comment: As said: the solution is obvious. Use phps ftp extension.

Comment: Yes, I get that. However, I'd much rather find a code snippet that I can modify to my needs, rather than learn all 34 PHP FTP functions. No point in re-inventing the wheel.\

Comment: As said: there are well working examples in the documentation. What else do you want? Some ready to use blackbox? Why? This is no rocket science, this is scripting. A few lines copied from the examples is all you need.

Comment: I looked at the link you sent, none of those examples were what I needed to do. Rather than being snarky with your replies, you could have provided something useful. All you did was point me to a page with a list of 34 different FTP functions. There's not much point in participating in a Question and Answer site if all you are going to do is tell people to go look it up. I already mentioned I searched for an answer, and wasn't having much luck, pointing me back to pages I have already read doesn't help at all.

Comment: Sorry. I tried to help. You did not provide _any_ details about what it is you want to do, so how do you expect us to answer with convenient solutions for exactly what you are looking for? Obviously you are not looking for help, but for someone how does your work for you. This is not what the stackexchange pages are about. I suggest you look for a place to hire a payed coder, maybe a freelancer. And that you read the explanations about how this place works. Thanks and bye.

Comment: I know how this place works. But I also see a lot of snarky replies from people when a simple direction towards something useful would work. I don't need someone to do the work for me, but pointing me to a page with a complete list of PHP FTP functions implies that you expect me to learn all of those right now in order to solve my problem. Obviously I know that I can learn all those functions and do it myself. My point is, when someone asks for help, your answer shouldn't be "go figure it out yourself". That's not help at all.

Comment: First, I did not point you to "some page", but to _the_ php documentation which should _always_ be the first place where you should look if you have a question about php. Second, I did _not_ post any reply, I posted a comment. There is a reason why comments and replies are separate. Third, no one asks you to learn a bunch of functions by heart. That makes zero sense and is not required. And fourth, and this is most important: you complain that my link did not answer specifically the task you have to solve, _but you never said what that task is_! You posted a totally vague question.

Comment: The question wasn't that vague. It said I need to copy files, server-to-server, via FTP, in a PHP script, and that it needed to retain the directory structure. That pretty much sums up what I'm trying to do. And yes, you pointed me to the PHP documentation page. Imagine if the next time you took your car to the garage they just told you to read the service manual for your car and you'd figure it out all on your own? While the documentation is the best place to look, it's not always the most practical, like in this case.

Comment: Sure it shows me all the functions, but not in a useful way unless I spend hours to figure out all the functions. If I had time to spend hours learning those functions tonight I wouldn't have posted here at all, would I? Either way, I found an answer, so have a good one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a PHP class that makes recursive FTP uploads and downloads easy. It can be found [here](https://vibhajadwani.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/php-recusively-ftp-download-and-upload/)

The code they used is below (The code at the top is example code for downloads, uploads, and error checking):

```
<?php // example
set_time_limit(0);
require 'ftp.php';


$ftp = new ftp();
$ftp->conn('host', 'username', 'password');
$ftp->get('download/demo', '/demo'); // download live "/demo" folder to local "download/demo"

$ftp->put('/demo/test', 'upload/vjtest'); // upload local "upload/vjtest" to live "/demo/test"

$arr = $ftp->getLogData();
if ($arr['error'] != "")
    echo '<h2>Error:</h2>' . implode('<br />', $arr['error']);
if ($arr['ok'] != "")
    echo '<h2>Success:</h2>' . implode('<br />', $arr['ok']);
```

---

```
class ftp {

    private $conn, $login_result, $logData, $ftpUser, $ftpPass, $ftpHost, $retry, $ftpPasv, $ftpMode, $verbose, $logPath, $createMask;

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Construct method
     *
     * @param   array   keys[passive_mode(true|false)|transfer_mode(FTP_ASCII|FTP_BINARY)|reattempts(int)|log_path|verbose(true|false)|create_mask(default:0777)]
     * @return void
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->retry = (isset($o['reattempts'])) ? $o['reattempts'] : 3;
        $this->ftpPasv = (isset($o['passive_mode'])) ? $o['passive_mode'] : true;
        $this->ftpMode = (isset($o['transfer_mode'])) ? $o['transfer_mode'] : FTP_BINARY;
        $this->verbose = (isset($o['verbose'])) ? $o['verbose'] : false;
        $this->logPath = (isset($o['log_path'])) ? $o['log_path'] : dirname(__FILE__).'\log'; 
        $this->createMask = (isset($o['create_mask'])) ? $o['create_mask'] : 0777;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Connection method
     *
     * @param   string  hostname
     * @param   string  username
     * @param   string  password
     * @return  void
     */
    public function conn($hostname, $username, $password)
    {   
        $this->ftpUser = $username;
        $this->ftpPass = $password;
        $this->ftpHost = $hostname;

        $this->initConn();
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Init connection method - connect to ftp server and set passive mode
     *
     * @return  bool
     */
    function initConn()
    {
        $this->conn = ftp_connect($this->ftpHost);
        $this->login_result = ftp_login($this->conn, $this->ftpUser, $this->ftpPass);
        if($this->conn && $this->login_result)
        {
            ftp_pasv($this->conn, $this->ftpPasv);
            return true;
        }       
        return false;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Put method - upload files(folders) to ftp server
     *
     * @param   string  path to destionation file/folder on ftp
     * @param   string  path to source file/folder on local disk
     * @param   int only for identify reattempt, dont use this param
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function put($destinationFile, $sourceFile, $retry = 0)
    {   
        if(file_exists($sourceFile))
        { 
            if(!$this->isDir($sourceFile, true))
            {
                $this->createSubDirs($destinationFile);
                if(!ftp_put($this->conn, $destinationFile, $sourceFile, $this->ftpMode))
                {
                    $retry++;
                    if($retry > $this->retry)
                    {
                        $this->logData('Error when uploading file: '.$sourceFile.' => '.$destinationFile, 'error');
                        return false;
                    }
                    if($this->verbose) echo 'Retry: '.$retry."\n";
                    $this->reconnect();
                    $this->put($destinationFile, $sourceFile, $retry);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->logData('Upload:'.$sourceFile.' => '.$destinationFile, 'ok');
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->recursive($destinationFile, $sourceFile, 'put');
            }
        }       
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Get method - download files(folders) from ftp server
     *
     * @param   string  path to destionation file/folder on local disk
     * @param   string  path to source file/folder on ftp server
     * @param   int only for identify reattempt, dont use this param
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function get($destinationFile, $sourceFile, $retry = 0)
    {
        if(!$this->isDir($sourceFile, false))
        {
            if($this->verbose)echo $sourceFile.' => '.$destinationFile."\n";
            $this->createSubDirs($destinationFile, false, true);
            if(!ftp_get($this->conn, $destinationFile, $sourceFile, $this->ftpMode))
            {
                $retry++;
                if($retry > $this->retry)
                {
                    $this->logData('Error when downloading file: '.$sourceFile.' => '.$destinationFile, 'error');
                    return false;
                }
                if($this->verbose) echo 'Retry: '.$retry."\n";
                $this->reconnect();
                $this->get($destinationFile, $sourceFile, $retry);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->logData('Download:'.$sourceFile.' => '.$destinationFile, 'ok');
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->recursive($destinationFile, $sourceFile, 'get');
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Make dir method - make folder on ftp server or local disk
     *
     * @param   string  path to destionation folder on ftp or local disk
     * @param   bool    true for local, false for ftp
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function makeDir($dir, $local = false)
    {
        if($local)
        {
            if(!file_exists($dir) && !is_dir($dir))return mkdir($dir, $this->createMask); else return true;
        }
        else
        {
            ftp_mkdir($this->conn,$dir);
            return ftp_chmod($this->conn, $this->createMask, $dir);
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Cd up method - change working dir up
     *
     * @param   bool    true for local, false for ftp
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function cdUp($local)
    {
        return $local ? chdir('..') : ftp_cdup($this->conn);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * List contents of dir method - list all files in specified directory
     *
     * @param   string  path to destionation folder on ftp or local disk
     * @param   bool    true for local, false for ftp
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function listFiles($file, $local = false)
    {
        if(!$this->isDir($file, $local))return false;
        if($local)
        {
            return scandir($file);
        }
        else
        {
            if(!preg_match('/\//', $file))
            {
                return ftp_nlist($this->conn, $file);
            }else
            {
                $dirs = explode('/', $file);
                foreach($dirs as $dir)
                {
                    $this->changeDir($dir, $local);
                }
                $last = count($dirs)-1;
                $this->cdUp($local);
                $list = ftp_nlist($this->conn, $dirs[$last]);
                $i = 0;
                foreach($dirs as $dir)
                {
                    if($i < $last) $this->cdUp($local);
                    $i++;
                }
                return $list;
            }
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Returns current working directory
     *
     * @param   bool    true for local, false for ftp
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function pwd($local = false)
    {
        return $local ? getcwd() : ftp_pwd($this->conn);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Change current working directory
     *
     * @param   string  dir name
     * @param   bool    true for local, false for ftp
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function changeDir($dir, $local = false)
    {
        return $local ? chdir($dir) : @ftp_chdir($this->conn, $dir);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Create subdirectories
     *
     * @param   string  path
     * @param   bool    
     * @param   bool    true for local, false for ftp
     * @param   bool    change current working directory back
     * @return  void
     */
    function createSubDirs($file, $last = false, $local = false, $chDirBack = true)
    {
        if(preg_match('/\//',$file))
        {
            $origin = $this->pwd($local);
            if(!$last) $file = substr($file, 0, strrpos($file,'/'));
            $dirs = explode('/',$file);
            foreach($dirs as $dir)
            {
                if(!$this->isDir($dir, $local))
                {
                    $this->makeDir($dir, $local);
                    $this->changeDir($dir, $local);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->changeDir($dir, $local);
                }
            }
            if($chDirBack) $this->changeDir($origin, $local);
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Recursion
     *
     * @param   string  destionation file/folder
     * @param   string  source file/folder
     * @param   string  put or get
     * @return  void
     */
    function recursive($destinationFile, $sourceFile, $mode)
    {
        $local = ($mode == 'put') ? true : false;
        $list = $this->listFiles($sourceFile, $local);
        if($this->verbose) echo "\n".'Folder: '.$sourceFile."\n";
        $this->logData(($mode=='get')?('Download:'):('Upload:').$sourceFile.' => '.$destinationFile, 'ok');       

        if($this->verbose) print_r($list);
        $x=0;
        $z=0;
        if(count($list)==2)// blank folder
        {
            if($mode == 'get')
                $this->makeDir($destinationFile, true);
            if($mode == 'put')
                $this->makeDir($destinationFile);
        }   
        foreach($list as $file)
        {
            if($file == '.' || $file == '..')continue;
            $destFile = $destinationFile.'/'.$file;
            $srcFile = $sourceFile.'/'.$file;
            if($this->isDir($srcFile,$local))
            {
                $this->recursive($destFile, $srcFile, $mode);
            }
            else
            {
                if($local)
                {
                    $this->put($destFile, $srcFile);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->get($destFile, $srcFile);
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Check if is dir
     *
     * @param   string  path to folder
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function isDir($dir, $local)
    {
        if($local) return is_dir($dir);
        if($this->changeDir($dir))return $this->cdUp(0);
        return false;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Save log data to array
     *
     * @param   string  data
     * @param   string  type(error|ok)
     * @return  void
     */
    function logData($data, $type)
    {
        $this->logData[$type][] = $data;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Get log data array
     *
     * @return  array
     */
    public function getLogData()
    {
        return $this->logData;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Save log data to file
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function logDataToFiles()
    {
        if(!$this->logPath) return false;
        $this->makeDir($this->logPath, true);
        $log = $this->getLogData();  
        $sep = "\n".date('y-m-d H:i:s').' ';
        if($log['error'] != "")
        {
            $logc = date('y-m-d H:i:s').' '.join($sep,$log['error'])."\n";
            $this->addToFile($this->logPath.'/'.$this->ftpUser.'-error.log',$logc);
        }
        if($log['ok'] != "")
        {
            $logc = date('y-m-d H:i:s').' '.join($sep,$log['ok'])."\n";
            $this->addToFile($this->logPath.'/'.$this->ftpUser.'-ok.log',$logc);
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Reconnect method
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function reconnect()
    {
        $this->closeConn();
        $this->initConn();
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Close connection method
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function closeConn()
    {
        return ftp_close($this->conn);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Write to file
     *
     * @param   string  path to file
     * @param   string  text
     * @param   string  fopen mode
     * @return  void
     */
    function addToFile($file, $ins, $mode = 'a')
    {
        $fp = fopen($file, $mode);
        fwrite($fp,$ins);
        fclose($fp);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Destruct method - close connection and save log data to file
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    function __destruct()
    {       
        $this->closeConn();
        $this->logDataToFiles();
    }
}

// END ftp class

/* End of file ftp.php */
/* Location: ftp.php */
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @jruizaranguren, I've included the code in my answer as well. If the site goes offline, or the linked page changes, the code is still available.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long. Copying a file over FTP using PHP might be as simple as

```
file_put_contents($fname
    , file_get_contents('FTP://ftp.example com/path/afile'));
```

But what do you know about where your PHP code is running? It may not have the capability to

- resolve DNS names
- make client connections to other/remote services
- create a listening data channel (for non-passive data channel)

And we can't answer these questions for you. Hence your first step is to get a proof of concept up and running using similar code to that above before you start worrying about lots of files, directories and synchronisation.

Why the requirement to implement this in PHP?

Comment: The servers we are copying the data from do not allow SSH access, and don't have SSL installed, so SFTP and FTPS are out. The only method available to download these files, besides the browser, is through FTP. Want to do it in PHP because that's the programming language I'm more familiar with. The "remote" servers are not ours, we have no control over them.

Comment: Also, we do not know the file structure on the remote server. So the script would need to download files and directories recursively.